# How do I undo bundle exec rake db:setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I undo `bundle exec rake db:setup`?

I ran it in the wrong rails app. I ran it in the [blogger](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html) when I should have ran it in the [blogger_advanced](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/blogger/static_pages.html) app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do  `rake db:drop`

.
It will drop  all tables (thats any tables created by setup, any migrations run by setup and any seeds created by setup)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `rake db:rollback` and it'll rollback migrations one by one, but if yours apps have same named models (User for example) it'll be lost. So you need to dump this tables first and recreate them later using database administrator tool.

And also it'll broke your `schema_migrations` table and you'll need to refill it by hands from your migration file names.

So if there is not much useful info, it's better to use @Alexphys approach.